# Crafter CMS: How to stop hung publishing process?

Tags: content-management-system, crafter-cms

In Crafter CMS, I attempted to publish changes to a document and it seems to be hung forever. Even if I shut it down and start it back up, it just gets stuck and I can't do anything with the document anymore.
I get the following error message in catalina.out every 10 seconds:

[INFO] 2017-09-22 12:51:56,847 [studioSchedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1] [job.DeployContentToEnvironmentStore] | Publishing is disabled for site mysite

I also notice in the mongod.log file, every few seconds it opens 51 connections and then a few seconds later closes them all and opens them back up again. It does this endlessly. Is that normal?

Why is publishing disabled? Is that a setting I need to change to enable it?

Is there some way to stop it so I can continue working? 
Right now I am completely stuck and may resort to blowing away the whole project and starting from scratch, but this is certainly not an acceptable once I get a few more documents created, so I hope there is an alternative.

Any ideas or help you can give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on 3.0.1 or 3.0.0, there is a publishing bug that's fixed in 3.0.2 development branch (not released yet, but you can build from source): https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms

If you don't want to upgrade to a development branch (understandable), a quick temporary fix is:
cd {crafterpath}/data/repos/sites/{yoursiteid}/published
git reset --hard
git pull -s recursive -Xtheirs origin master

If you have delivery nodes that are wired to this site, then you can blow away the git folder on the delivery and it'll rebuild itself (if you're seeing issues with deployment to delivery nodes). If this is live, take node out of the load-balancer first etc.

Expect the issue to come up again and for you to need to git reset/pull again until you upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. I think I'm on 3.0.1. I will probably get the development branch for now since I'm still evaluating it, so it's nothing critical.

Comment: I have updated to the latest development branch, and though it seems to have improved, I am still having problems with publishing. I tried doing a bulk publish because I was unable to get a context menu for any script that has braces in the name like {id}.get.groovy, so I was unable to publish it. After the bulk publish, for those files it just continued spinning. A look in the logs shows it giving the same endless message as before about publishing being disabled.

Comment: The git reset/pull procedure doesn't solve the problem, so my site is once again hosed. Hopefully I can get my content migrated to a fresh site without completely starting over.